# Submit with javascript

Tags: java, javascript, html, htmlunit

I am trying to login on a page with HtmlUnit, but is seems like the login-button is a javascript-link. This is the page: `https://www.talkmore.no/talkmore3/servlet/Login`

I find the username/password input, and adding value to this, but not the submit button.

This is my code:

```
HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("https://www.talkmore.no/talkmore3/servlet/Login");
HtmlForm form = page.getFormByName("login");
List<HtmlInput> inputs = getInputs(form); 
form.getInputByName("username").setValueAttribute("user");
form.getInputByName("password").setValueAttribute("pass");
page = form.getInputByValue("Login").click();
```

Innputs in the form:

```
[HtmlTextInput[<input class="inputModern" style="width: 100px;" maxlength="8" name="username" type="text" value="">], HtmlPasswordInput[<input class="inputModern" style="width: 100px;" name="password" type="password" value="">]]
```

No sign for submit..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viewing the page's source you can see that it uses JS to submit the form:

```
<a href="javascript:document.login.submit();"><span>Logg inn</span></a>
```

I'm not familiar with HtmlUnit but could you not trigger a click on that? Something like (this is mostly guesswork):

```
HTMLAnchor anchor = page.getAnchorByHref("javascript:document.login.submit();"); 
anchor.click();
```